# Подключить Oracle к Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Делал все по инструкциям.
Загрузил instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0. Распаковал, добавил в системную переменную "Путь".
Скачал php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64, распаковал, добавил в системную переменную "Путь".
Указал extension_dir, раскоментировал extension=oci8_12c, перезагрузил.
Запускаю Composer-Setup.exe, выходит ошибка

> Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (%1 не является приложением
> Win32).

Всё скачивалось 64, причем здесь Win32, попробовал все рекомендации интернетов, успехом не увенчалось, подскажите пож. как быть.

Comment: _Загрузил instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0_, а где вы взяли этот клиент, на официальном саите такого нет?

Comment: так, и впрямь нет, неужели сам туплю?, перекачаю, отпишу.

Comment: Загрузил instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0,  php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64, та же ошибка. А у вас подобный набор срабатывает?

Comment: У меня такого набора быть не может, я не работаю под windows. Скачайте последнею версию 19.11, с ней тоже должно работать.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru вызывает ту же ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0 (годовой давности), сменил версию php c 8 на 7.4, и все заработало. Стоило это несколько дней тупой переборки всех доступных вариантов, пока не нашел сохранившийся старый оракловский клиент. В интернете ничего толкового никто не советовал. Я в веб разработке совсем недавно, может кто скажет, как эту проблему по-уму надо было решать? (да и не до конца она решена, с восьмеркой по прежнему не работает)

Comment: _пока не нашел сохранившийся старый оракловский клиент_, 19.3.0.0 не старый, 12.2.0.1.0 где-то на 5 лет старее.

Comment: В смысле скачивал год назад, сейчас же 19.11 на сайте предлагается

Comment: А какая у вас версия БД?

Comment: 12, но проблема же появляется еще до попыток соединения?

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе: *instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0*, по видимому, сборка для устаревших версий Windows NT, 2000. Она не будет работать на новых версиях.

Устанавливаемый клиент должен соответствовать по архитектуре и разрядности приложениям его использующим. Скачивать следует с [официального сайта](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html).

Для Windows 64 bit [instantclient-basic-windows.x64-xx.x.x.x](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html). В самом низу страницы по этой ссылке, есть инструкция по установке *Instant Client Installation for Microsoft Windows 64-bit*. **Необходимо учесть**, впеременная окружения `Path` не должна содержать путей от старых установок клиента, что можно проверить в команднoй строке: `C:\Users\iam> path`.

Версия клиента xx.x.x.x должна быть не ниже версии БД, выше допускается.

Comment: да, мне уже указали на мой косяк  с версией, но далее я ставил и instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0 и  instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru, но ошибка сохранилась. А вы не тестировали на эти версии на совместимость с php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64?

Comment: _но ошибка сохранилась_, они не могут ту же ошибку вызывать, у них нет oci8_12c.dll. Посмотрите по путям в Path, вы всё убрали там от предыдущих попыток. В ответе показано - как.

Comment: на всякий случай еще раз перепроверил Path, там все норм. Так oci8_12c.dll пытается же загрузиться из-за того, что раскоментрирована её загрузка в php.ini?

Comment: Ещё раз, посмотрите в папку, куда вы установили клиента, там oci8_12c.dll нету.  Где вы взяли _instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru_?

Comment: Взял https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html. Я не вдавался к сожалению глубоко в теорию, но везде пишут, для успешного подсоединения к Oracle из ларавела, необходимо поставить клиент и загружать oci8_12c.dll из %php%/ext. Как они взаимодействуют между собой, для меня увы, неизвестно.

Comment: Тут особо глубоко в теорию вдаваться не надо, если oci8_12c.dll не существует, то её загрузить невозможно. Исправте на oci.dll.

Comment: А как вы объясните, что если я поставлю клиент 9.3, то при смене php 8 / 7.4, а oci8_12c.dll содержится в папке ext в обоих версиях, под одинаковым названием, лишь версии разные, в первом случае ошибка происходит, а в другом нет, кроме как конфликтом версий?

Comment: Version 19.11.0.0.0
Base - one of these packages is required
Name 
Basic Package 
Download
instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru.zip
Только что откопипастил с указанного адреса, или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: По поводу _instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru.zip_, извините, проглядел. А по поводу oci8_12c.dll, пока не знаю. Попробовать не могу, у меня нет windows. Попозже посмотрю ещё раз, но главное из ответа остаётся в силе - если архитектура приложения и библиотеки отличается, то библиотека не загрузится.

Comment: Посмотрел ещё раз. Почему вы указываете extension=oci8_12c.dll, если в дистрибуции поставляется php_oci8_12c.dll?

Comment: В пояснении самого ини-файла написано: "If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following syntax: extension=modulename. For example: extension=mysqli". При этом название длл-ки - php_mysqli.dll. И так у всех, поэтому по аналогии раскоментировал  эту строку. Предполагаю, что при загрузке префикс добавляется .